# How to generate Account folder in ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, account

I wanted to add the build-in Account folder like this in my ASP.NET but I could not find it anywhere.
[expected folder in red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YegYe.png)

I have tried these steps below:

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXqI8.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJbR9.png)

[screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5jlj.png)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your creation of project, in authentication part, change it from no authentication to any of those, if sql based authentication choose `individual`

[Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5iS6.png)

then the account folder will be created

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, it worked. I did not check that button last time =))